# How can I extract keys and values from a string when the value contains the separator between keys and values or the separator between pairs?

Tags: rust

How can I efficiently extract the key-value pairs from a string into a `HashMap` when

- `key` is always followed by `:` and then the value
- `value` ends with a `,` followed by another `key` (sometimes whitespace and then `key`)
- `value` can contain `, :` throughout
- no `value` will include any `key`
- the order of the `key`s are not fixed
- the `key` names are known

For these key-value pairs

```
key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:anothe:r val,ue,
```

It should produce this `HashMap`:

```
"key1", "value1"
"key2", "this is, some value2"
"key3", "anothe:r val,ue"
```

I have tried the following code but it is no good with just a `,` as a delimiter as the value can contain commas throughout.

```
"key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:anothe:r val,ue,"
    .split(",")
    .map(|kv| kv.splitn(2, ":").collect::<Vec<&str>>())
    .filter(|vec| vec.len() == 2)
    .map(|vec| (vec[0].trim().into(), vec[1].trim().into()))
    .collect()
```

My thought would be to provide a list of keys: `["key1", "key2", "key3"]` to use as delimiters

**UPDATE:**

Using @Lucretiel answer I have come up with:

```
fn key_value<'a>(keys: &[&str], mut command: &'a str) -> HashMap<&'a str, &'a str> {
    let mut hashmap = HashMap::new();
    loop {
        if let Some(key) = key(&keys, &command) {
            command = &command[key.len() + 1..];

            let value = value(&keys, &command);
            let trim: &[_] = &[',', ' '];
            command = &command[value.len()..].trim_start_matches(trim);

            hashmap.insert(key, value);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    hashmap
}

fn key<'a>(keys: &[&str], command: &'a str) -> Option<&'a str> {
    let regex = format!("^({}):", keys.join("|"));
    let regex = regex::Regex::new(&regex).expect("Invalid regex");
    match regex.shortest_match(&command) {
        Some(position) => Some(&command[..position - 1]),
        None => None,
    }
}

fn value<'a>(keys: &[&str], command: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    let regex = format!(r#",\s*({}):"#, keys.join("|"));
    let regex = regex::Regex::new(&regex).expect("Invalid regex");
    match regex.find(&command) {
        Some(position) => &command[..position.start()],
        None => command,
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=334da071c620fbb24773023bce48f1fa))

Comment: So how do you know when you've reached the end of `value1`? Is it fixed-width, or is it quoted in some way, or is it just guaranteed not to contain the string `key2:`, or what?

Comment: The value is guaranteed not to include the `key2:`. So end of value1 will be a `,` and then `key2:` which we can provide a possible list of keys to check.

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual code to solve this is nontrivial, but it can be done. There's a lot of little fiddly edge cases, depending on what error cases you want to account for (for instance, do you require that *every* key in your known key list is present in the input string to parse? Do you allow duplicate keys? etc.). The basic algorithm looks like this:

- while the key list isn't empty:

  - find the key that starts the string, matching `^{key}:`. This is the current key.

    - if there is no such key, it's an error; the input is malformed
  - find the *next* earliest key in the string, matching `,\s*{key}:`. This is the next key.

    - if there are no more keys, the remainder of the string is the value for this key
    - otherwise, all the content between the two found keys is the current value
  - add (current key, current value) to your hash table
  - remove current key from the key list (assuming you don't accept duplicate keys)
  - slice the (current key, current value) off the front of your input string
- Once you're out of keys, return the hash map

There's no way to do this with a conventional grammar; as presented it's very ambiguous. However, if you structure your parsing around scanning for each subsequent key (assuming that keys never appear as substrings in values) you can successfully parse this kind of input.

The algorithm as described runs in quadratic time, but hypothetically it should be reducible to linear time if you create a composite regular expression to search for every key simultaneously:

`,\s*(key1|key2|key3|...):`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't as clean as using iterators, but here's one idea. Reading the keys and values is difficult if you read the string from the start due to having to do lookahead to tell whether what you're reading is still part of the value or the next key.

Reading the string backwards, however, is much easier. The last value is everything after the last `':'`. The last key is everything from the last `','` before that to that last `':'`.

For example we'll use your string.

```
"key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:another val,ue,"
                                             ^ the last ':'
```

```
"key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:another val,ue,"
                                       ^ the last ',' before that
```

```
"key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:another val,ue,"
                  ^ the last ':' before that
```

```
"key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:another val,ue,"
            ^ the last ',' before that
```

```
"key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:another val,ue,"
     ^ the last ':' before that
```

As you can see, this perfectly splits up the string into keys and values.

To actually code this, we'll have a slice which always refers to the part of the string we haven't covered yet. At each step we'll find the last `':'` (or `','`) and change the slice to point before that. Using `rsplitn` works fairly well here, but I'm sure there's another way.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut kv = Vec::new();
    let mut slice = "key1:value1, key2:this is, some value2, key3:another val,ue,";
    while !slice.is_empty() {
        let mut split = slice.rsplitn(2, ':');
        // `rsplitn` will always return at least one slice,
        // namely the whole string if there aren't any matches.
        // So we can unwrap here.
        let value = split.next().unwrap().trim();
        // You may want to decide to do something else here.
        // The only way `split.next()` will be `None` is if
        // The input string has incorrect syntax.
        slice = split.next().unwrap_or("");

        let mut split = slice.rsplitn(2, ',');
        // similar reasoning here
        let key = split.next().unwrap().trim();
        slice = split.next().unwrap_or("");

        kv.push((key, value));
    }
    println!("{:?}", kv);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59bce2ac5cdeda8e7e5d55893ac65800)

Just one note. The code above counts any trailing commas as part of the last value. If you don't want that, you can do a check. Don't forget to `trim` the string first (and this may be worth doing anyway)! In the future, [`strip_suffix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.strip_suffix) would work well here. For now, `str::ends_with` should do fine.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response! One problem I failed to mention is that value can have any character including `:`

Comment: @James Then your grammar is ambiguous. Does `foo: bar, baz: qux` have two keys and two values (`"foo": "bar"` and `"baz": "qux"`) or one key and one value `"foo": "bar, baz: qux"`?

Comment: two keys and two values

Comment: @James The point is you need some more constraints for this to be a well-defined problem. You mentioned elsewhere that you have a list of keys available. That might help, but there are still some constraints that need to be specified.